# Getting Crash(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090095) while fragment change Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got below error while changing the fragment page.

```
  Process: com.iance, PID: 26061
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090095 (com.inance:id/fragment_replace) for fragment myFragment{9fcc0b3 #12 id=0x7f090095}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1422)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)


IN Activity

   ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new HomeFragment(), "HomeDashBoard");
    adapter.addFrag(new NotificationFragment(), "Notification");
    adapter.addFrag(new ProfileFragment(), "Profile");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);




class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // return null to display only the icon
        return null;
    }
}


In HomeFragment:

    @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

       ChildFragment chilfragment = new ChildFragment ();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_replace, chilfragment );
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
 }


home fragment.xml:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_replace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
 Thanks in advance
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177357/no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment

Comment: show your fragment change code with parent activity xml

Comment: i have mentioned what i am trying here @TejasPandya

Comment: where is `fragment_replace` has been placed ?

Comment: check updated code @TejasPandya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your  `ViewPagerAdapter` try changing  from `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager()`

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new HomeFragment(), "HomeDashBoard");
    adapter.addFrag(new NotificationFragment(), "Notification");
    adapter.addFrag(new ProfileFragment(), "Profile");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```