# No view found for id for fragment InspectionDetailsFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception

I have the following XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_buttons_container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    android:text="@string/details"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/gold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGray"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_title"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_title"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_title" />


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_status_til"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_title">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_status_tie"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="@string/status" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_start_time_til"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_status_til">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_start_time_tie"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="@string/start_time" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_end_time_til"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_start_time_til">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_end_time_tie"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="@string/end_time" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_desc_time_til"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_end_time_til">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_desc_time_tie"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:hint="@string/description" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_handling_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    android:text="@string/handling"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/gold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_desc_time_til" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    android:background="@color/lightGray"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_handling_title"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_handling_title"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_handling_title" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_outcome_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    android:text="@string/outcome"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_handling_title" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_outcome_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/size_8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_outcome_title" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/size_16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_outcome_spinner">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_outcome_report_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Outcome report" />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_inspection_details_buttons_container"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/white_background_gray_rounded_border"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="@dimen/size_0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/size_16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/white_background_gray_rounded_border"
                android:text="@string/handle"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

and the following code -

```kotlin
class InspectionDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(inspection: Inspection): InspectionDetailsFragment {
            val inspectionDetailsFragment = InspectionDetailsFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putParcelable(Constants.INSPECTION, inspection)
            inspectionDetailsFragment.arguments = bundle
            return inspectionDetailsFragment
        }
    }

...
...

}
```

```kotlin
//Inside another Fragment
 changeFragment(
                parentFragmentManager, R.id.fragment_inspection_details_root,
                InspectionDetailsFragment.newInstance(inspection), true
            )

// Change fragment extension function to handle navigation easily
@SuppressLint("PrivateResource")
fun changeFragment(fragmentManager: FragmentManager?, @IdRes containerId: Int, fragment: Fragment?, addToBackStack: Boolean = false) {
    if (fragmentManager == null) return
    val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    if (addToBackStack) fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
    /*fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(
        R.anim.abc_fade_in,
        R.anim.abc_shrink_fade_out_from_bottom,
        R.anim.abc_grow_fade_in_from_bottom,
        R.anim.abc_popup_exit
    )*/
    fragment?.let {
        fragmentTransaction
            .replace(containerId, it, it::class.java.simpleName)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

For some reason when trying to navigate to the InspectionDetailsFragment the app crashes with the `No view found for id 0x7f0900df (com.supercom.myapplication:id/fragment_inspection_details_root) for fragment InspectionDetailsFragment` I really have no idea what's wrong, I tried to look up but it seems like I am doing everything correct.

The InspectionDetailsFragment used to have a container fragment for it but I deleted it, maybe that is related to the issue I am getting?

Comment: What does it say in your onCreateView or onViewCreated?

Comment: @KristyWelsh Never reaches that place, crashes before it.

Comment: the problem here is your putting wrong layout or its might be missing.
on changeFragment fun change your navigation to 
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace("your current fragment id", fragmentyouwanttogo).commit.
Check on this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35177357/no-view-found-for-id-for-fragment
let me know if I answer your question